# Grails and ACEGI security plugin - How to prevent login from security event listener?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have the following event listener in SecurityConfig

```
security {

  active = true
  useSecurityEventListener = true

  //...

  onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent  = { e, appCtx ->
    // handle InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent

    //how to cancel user login from here??    
  }

}
```

How to prevent user from logging in from that point?

Comment: try ask your question in the Grails user group, too http://www.grails.org/Mailing+lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is once you receive the event, the user is already logged in. What I believe you need to do is create a custom [AccessDecisionVoter](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/vote/AccessDecisionVoter.html) to perform your access logic. I haven't tried it myself but the [spring security plugin docs](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Customizing+with+SecurityConfig) (voters section) give some details on how to set one up. It looks simple enough judging by the code for the [acegi AuthenticatedVoter](http://www.javakey.net/source/acegi-security/1.x/org/acegisecurity/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dave, there is no way to programmatically do logout in acegi plugin??